# How does the pthread_cond_wait() actually work?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

So the idea of **`pthread_cond_wait()`** is that it will unlock the mutex and wait for the condition.

Lets suppose that you would manually unlock the mutex first and then wait for a condition. Within that timeframe, between those two operations, you have to assume that something bad can happen, another thread will lock the mutex, which is not good. The same goes for if you first wait and then unlock, that is not possible.

So, here comes my question:
how does **`pthread_cond_wait()`** actually work?

The thread calls the function and passes a locked mutex and therafter waits on the condition to settle?

How does another thread then modify the variable, if it is already locked by this thread?

My first thought was, that the mutex has to be recursive, however being recursive only allows the same thread to lock the mutex multiple times.

Comment: Do some research on *atomic operations*. The unlock and changing the state of the thread to waiting happens in one atomic operation, possibly inside the operating system kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I haven't just google the specification for the **`pthread_cond_wait()`**.

I guess I didn't completely know what my question will turn out to be, when I started.

Anyways the answer to my question can be found here:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html